# Did Salesforce.com's Winter '13 version change/break Set.contains() method?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

We have our sandbox upgraded to Winter '13, but our production environment is still on the old version.  The following code prints "false" on our sandbox, but "true" on production.  I can't seem to find mention of this on line, but it looks like they work differently!

```
Set<Id> x = new Set<Id>{
     '012A0000000qv2wIAA'
    ,'012A0000000qv2xIAA'
    ,'012A0000000qv2yIAA'
    ,'012A0000000qv2zIAA'
};

System.debug(x.contains('012A0000000qv2z'));
```

Note that the Set contains 18-character IDs, and we're asking if it .contains() a 15-character ID.  I don't mind it working one way or the other;  just weird that it's behaving differently.

---

EDIT: Just noticed that if I explicitly cast the String to an ID, the behavior becomes consistent across environments:

```
System.debug(x.contains((Id)('012A0000000qv2z')));
```

So maybe Apex has changed the type-promotion rules in the new release?

Comment: You might get a better response on the dedicated salesforce stack exchange site: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look into this.  This is an unintentional change to the type manipulation logic in the new implementation of Set in Apex (the new impl supports user defined types, hooray!).  I've filed a bug and we'll address this in a future patch (I'm not allowed to make promises as to when).  Thanks for pointing out this issue and giving such a concise repro.

Greg Fee